# How do you import plugins from a jar file in gradle?

Tags: gradle, plugins, offline

I am working on a Gradle project where I would like to import plugins without having to reach out to a remote server. If I had a jar file for the plugin how would I be able to let the Gradle build script know where it is and how to import the plugin in 'plugin {}'.